# how to uninstall fdupes from ubuntu

Tags: uninstall, duplicate-files, software-uninstall

I have installed `fdupes`.  I would like to know the authenticity of the program, any review would be highly appreciated.

Now I want to uninstall the program from Ubuntu.  Please help with the steps.

thanks.

Comment: you can try DuplicateFilesDeleter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on terminal,

```
sudo apt-get purge fdupes
```

Comment: can i use the `fdupes` utility to check the duplicate files in windows after mount the windows drive? thanks.

Comment: search for the above question in this site,if you doesn't find anything then ask it as a question.